# How to export/import a Photoshop action from one Windows computer to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I switched computers and I need a Photoshop action I used on the previous computer. None of the instructions I found online helped so far. :(

I call the action on the old computer (Windows 7, Photoshop CS5.1) from this screen (`File > Scripts > Image Processor`). It's named "Logo pe poze".

[image: Photoshop custom script]

I exported and imported the `C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS5.1/Presets` folder but the script doesn't show up on the new environment (Windows 8, Photoshop CC 14.2).

I also tried searching for files with the action's name and nothing came up in Windows 7. Also nothing when I search for `*.atn` (the common extension for actions).

Can someone tell me please what else I can try to copy this action over? I also need to know for future reference.

Comment: Is it a script or an action? If action, have you saved the action?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the difference. I think it's a script since I call it from `File > Scripts`.

Comment: I'm quite sure it has to do with the versions (5.1 to CC). It seems like some versions require a migration tool (see [*here*](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4287533)), and there are a few articles on migrating CS4 to CS5 and even 5 to 5.1 but I can't find anything for CC. Still, 'migration' would be a good term to add to the search :/

Comment: @Scott, I was wrong. Turns out it's an **action** even though I'm accessing it from `File > Scripts`.

@Yisela, your comment pointed me to the [solution](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/move-actions-presets-workspaces-photoshop.html). Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found [instructions](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/move-actions-presets-workspaces-photoshop.html) for **exporting** just the actions you need.

1. View your actions by going to `Window > Actions`.
2. If your actions aren't contained in a set, create one by clicking the folder icon at the bottom of the action widget.

[image: Create new action set in Photoshop]

3. Drag the actions you need into the new set.

[image: Photoshop move actions in the new set.PNG]

4. Make sure you have the action set selected.
5. From the menu in the Actions widget ([image: Photoshop actions menu.png]) choose `Save Actions`.

[image: Photoshop save actions]

This will create a `*.atn` file. On the other computer follow these steps to **import** the actions:

1. View actions by going to `Window > Actions`.
2. From the menu in the Actions widget ([image: Photoshop actions menu.png]) choose `Load Actions`.

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. That was my thought.. an action, which you need to first save in order to move. You should mark this as the correct answer if it solved the question -- it's okay that it's your answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

First, move the actions into a folder. 
 
[image: Click on the Folder Icon to create a Folder them Move your Actions]

Then 
1.) select the folder with actions you want to export.

2.) Click on the menu in the top Right corner and save actions to a folder (or USB key.. anywhere you like)

[image]

3.) Finally. Go to the computer you want to load actions, click action pallete menu and load actions >> Select the atn file we created in above steps.

4). You are done.. :) enjoy..

Comment: Hi Roshan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, but I fail to see how your answer adds to Nelu's. Please do not duplicate answers unless you are adding significant new info. Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!